# how to configure neo4j to use rails test and fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I'm running neo4j 2.1.5 and rake test (not rspec) for testing on rails 4.2.0.beta4 and ruby 2.1.2, but it returns

```
test/test_helper.rb:10:in <class:TestCase>: undefined method 'fixtures' for ActiveSupport::TestCase:Class (NoMethodError)
from /home/pdipietro/gsn/test/test_helper.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/pdipietro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:15:in `require'
from /home/pdipietro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:15:in `block in <main>'
from /home/pdipietro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
from /home/pdipietro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
```

This is my text_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
 fixtures :all

end
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you also using ActiveRecord? From what I can see, the `fixtures` method is defined as part of it, it may not be available otherwise.

Comment: $ gem list active

     *** LOCAL GEMS ***

     active_attr (0.8.4)
     activejob (4.2.0.beta4)
     activemodel (4.2.0.beta4, 4.1.8)
     activerecord (4.2.0.beta4, 4.1.8)
     activesupport (4.2.0.beta4, 4.1.8)